# Make woocommerce full width on wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make the woo commerce area of my site take up 100% of the page width (the blue highlighted section).

Unticking width 75% in the attached picture does the job, but it seems tied into a bootstrapped grid layout which is something i do not understand and makes me think it will not work properly at different sizes?

Chrome dev tools image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.woocommerce div#primary {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Well, your theme ( metrostore ) has a sidebar. Maybe you can disable that sidebar in theme options.  Otherwise adding this css above would make your store full width.